# Real-time Transport Protocol is not used in youtube?

Tags: network-programming, voip, rtp

I came across reading about real time protocol in Wikipedia, which mentions the following :
"RTP is used extensively in communication and entertainment systems that involve streaming media"

I was curious about this protocol and wanted to see this in wireshark. I thought youtube.com might be using RTP when running videos, but was surprised to see that only TCP packets are being sent when a video is being played.

Can someone please tell another free website which implements RTP, so that I will be able to see it in wireshark. (I am actually wanting to explore network optimization opportunity in my server applications by using RTP, since it is ok to loose a few packets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Computer Networks](http://books.google.com/books?id=Pd-z64SJRBAC&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=what%20site%20uses%20Real-time_Transport_Protocol&source=bl&ots=RCMMExUX9C&sig=1LJ8F1v2IVv1bG8rOl_NCaPl1Dg&hl=zh-CN&ei=bCCQTbCvG4-cvgOC2Y2tDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CB8Q6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q&f=false), RTP is the *payload* of UDP (or TCP) as the book indicates.

Here is a picture from the book:

[image]

According to [WireShark's wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP), only RTP on UDP could be detected by WireShark. (Thanks to [Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413251/ralf))

Comment: Wireshark recognises RTP packets, at least over UDP. IIRC the TCP wasn't implemented a couple of months ago, but I'm not sure what the latest status is.

Comment: @Ralf, according to wiki.wireshark, still not.

Comment: it can, sometimes, at least v. 1.4.0. It was recognizing (sometimes!) RTP packets in RTSP interleaved session

Comment: @Andy T, really? Maybe you could post a new answer.

Comment: this info is not relevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

Youtube uses HTTP AFAIK. Also, keep in mind that RTP can be sent over UDP as well as TCP.

An RTSP server can be used to start an RTP media session. I don't know any public servers, but another option would be to download the [live555](http://www.live555.com) RTSP server. There are also some example media files. Then all you need to do is build the media server application as well as the openRTSP client and use the client app to connect to the server for the stream. The client can request RTP over UDP, TCP, etc.

Alternatively you could also use Darwin Streaming Server as an RTSP server.

Comment: "Youtube uses HTTP AFAIK" You mean Web Sockets right?